# Comparison of Regex

Tags: regex, shell, unix

I wish to search whether a string contains 'CI' in middle no matter what length it is. The letters may appear any where and the length can be variable. Also I wish to use this as a conditional switch For a shell script. So any command which can be used inside IF to determine whether a string contains this. Appreciate help as this gives insight of how to use this.

Answer (score 1):

not regex but works with POSIX sh (more portable)

```
case "$FOO" in
*CI*)
    # do something
    ;;
esac
```

regex sh

```
if expr "$FOO" : '.*CI' >/dev/null; then 
    # do something
fi

if echo "$FOO" | grep 'CI' >/dev/null; then
    # do something
fi
```

not regex with many shells (bash ksh)

```
if [[ $FOO = *CI* ]]; then
    # do something
fi
```

regex bash specific

```
if [[ $FOO =~ CI ]]; then
    # do something
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
echo $FOO | grep CI
```

I guess.